# How to create an array inside root element on mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this data that i moddeling after i imported a csv file:

```
 {Main: {
    "Name" : "MainNAme1",
    "age" : "age1",
    "ge" :"ge1",
    {Crs:{[
           {Cr: {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5a75baada0f20bd4e612d480"),
                "Number" : 400,
                "Page" : 24,
                "DC" : "NE",
            }},
           {Cr: {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5a75baada0f20bd4e612d489"),
                "Number" : 300,
                "Page" : 14,
                "DC" : "100",
            }},
     ]}},
}}
```

And i would like to know how can i create an new array inside a root element like this:

```
    {Main: {
    "Name" : "MainNAme1",
    "info":[{
        "age" : "age1",
        "ge" :"ge1",
     }],
    {Crs:{[
           {Cr: {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5a75baada0f20bd4e612d480"),
                "Number" : 400,
                "Page" : 24,
                "DC" : "NE",
            }},
           {Cr: {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5a75baada0f20bd4e612d489"),
                "Number" : 300,
                "Page" : 14,
                "DC" : "100",
            }},
     ]}},
}}
```

I'm using aggregate to moddeling this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off your OP. You are looking to move `age` and `ge` into its own array. You could use `$addToSet` during your `$group` stage

Try adding this into your `$group` pipline:

```
"Info" : { $addToSet : { "age": "$age", "ge" : "$ge" } } }}
```

output

```
"Info" : [ 
    {
        "age" : "age1",
        "ge" : "ge1"
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage which is available from MongoDB v3.4 onwards. Before that you'd need to use `$project`.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $addFields: {
        "info": [{
            "age": "$Main.age",
            "ge": "$Main.ge"
        }]
    }
})
```